# How can i count the occurences of vector item in R?

Tags: r, vector, find-occurrences

I am newest in using the **R** Language. I want to get the item with the maximum occurences in the vector.
 So, if i have a vector as bellow: `vec<-as.vector(c(1,2,3,1,4,1,2))`.
 I want get **1**.

Thanks.

Comment: Something among these lines `res <- table(vec) ; as.numeric(names(res)[which.max(res)])`

Comment: `sort(table(vec),decreasing=TRUE)[1]`

Comment: @AvinashRaj more like `as.numeric(names(sort(table(vec),decreasing=TRUE)))[1]` prbably

Comment: `x[which.max(ave(x,x,FUN=length))]`